# How do I access data in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, var

```
  var lotsData = [
    {
        index: 0,
        data: 'I want to be in HTML',

    },
    {
        index: 1,
        data: 'I dont' want to be in HTML',
    }]
```

Lets say I prefer to have one var with an array. How do I access the index 0, say its connected to a click event and I want to use data:

```
    $('.tab').live('click', function() {
          console.log("I was clicked");
                      $('#fancy').text(WHAT GOES HERE TO ACCESS data from index 0?);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is written in Javascript, and Javascript itself provides the Array object.

So accessing the 0th element of an array is `array_name[0]`

In your example, you're storing objects as the elements of the array. Your objects are including an "index" property, but **beware,** your "index" property has nothing to do with the element index in the array. You should NOT include an "index" property... Eg:

```
 var lotsData = [
{ // this is the first array element, index value in the array is 0
    index: 1,
    data: 'I want to be in HTML',

},
{  // this is the second array element, index value in the array is 1
    index: 0,
    data: "I don't want to be in HTML",
}]

lotsData[0].data // value: 'I want to be in HTML'
```

The better example would be:

```
 var lotsData = [
{  // this is the first array element, index value in the array is 0
    category: 'shoe',
    detail: 'red'

},
{  // this is the second array element, index value in the array is 1
    category: 'fruit',
    detail: 'apple'
}]

lotsData[0].detail // value: 'red'
```

**Added: trailing commas**

Note that while Javascript is a powerful language, it does have its quirks.
An important one is trailing commas, such as

```
...
    index: 0,
    data: "I don't want to be in HTML",  // Trailing comma. DON'T DO THIS!
}]
```

The problem is that the trailing comma is not a formal part of the Javascript language. Most JS engines support it, but a very important one does not: the Internet Explorer browser does **not** support trailing commas and will die a sad death when it encounters one.

Your testing should always include IE due to its unique ways of doing things.

I test in IE 7.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm a Rubyist indexing functions the same way

Comment: @JZ thanks for the check! I'm also a Rubyist and been delighted as I learn more and more Javascript--it is quite a powerful, full featured language. Of course, it isn't ruby, but it has far more power than its (old) reputation led me to believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.tab').live('click', function() {
          console.log("I was clicked");
                      $('#fancy').text(lotsData[0].data);
        });
```

of course this is assuming your indexes are in correct order (as they seem to be from your example data).

And in that case there is no reason to keep a `index` property of your array'd objects.  using a simple string array would be much easier to work with.

example

```
var lotsData = ["I want to be in HTML","I don't want to be in HTML"];
```

this way you would just have to simply reference `lotsData[0]`

Answer (score 1):

First off don't use .live() unless you really really need to ( http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live )

But if you look at the .live() documentation ( http://api.jquery.com/live/ ) you will see the fact that you can pass data to .live(), that will be available in the callback.

> .live( eventType, eventData, handler )

So:

```
$('.tab').live('click',lotsData,function(event){
    console.log('I was clicked');
    $('#fancy').text(event.data[0].data);
});
```

Is that what you are asking?

Or are you looking at a a way to iterate through lotsdata and find out which item in the array has .index = 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, not best solutuion:

```
$('.tab').live('click', function() {
    console.log("I was clicked");
    var realIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < lotsData.length; i++ )
    {
        if (lotsData[i].index == 0) {
            realIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    $('#fancy').text(lotsData[realIndex].index);
});
```